# Why do I get an infinite loop when processing neighbouring cells in Minesweeper using a queue?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, minesweeper

I'm coding a minesweeper game, and when the user clicks an empty cell, all the reachable empty cells must be opened as well.

I'm using a queue to do so, but it seems like I'm having a trouble with an infinite loop.

The part of the code with the problem:

```
queue<int> q;
q.push(row);
q.push(col);

while(!q.empty()){
    int tempRow = q.front();
    int tempCol = q.front();

    if((tempRow-1)>=0 && (tempRow-1)<s && (tempCol-1)>=0 && (tempCol-1)<s && table[tempRow-1][tempCol-1]==' '){q.push(tempRow-1);q.push(tempCol-1);}
    if((tempRow-1)>=0 && (tempRow-1)<s && (tempCol)>=0 && (tempCol)<s && table[tempRow-1][tempCol]==' '){q.push(tempRow-1);q.push(tempCol);}
    if((tempRow-1)>=0 && (tempRow-1)<s && (tempCol+1)>=0 && (tempCol+1)<s && table[tempRow-1][tempCol+1]==' '){q.push(tempRow-1);q.push(tempCol+1);}
    if((tempRow)>=0 && (tempRow)<s && (tempCol-1)>=0 && (tempCol-1)<s && table[tempRow][tempCol-1]==' '){q.push(tempRow);q.push(tempCol-1);}
    if((tempRow)>=0 && (tempRow)<s && (tempCol+1)>=0 && (tempCol+1)<s && table[tempRow][tempCol+1]==' '){q.push(tempRow);q.push(tempCol+1);}
    if((tempRow+1)>=0 && (tempRow+1)<s && (tempCol-1)>=0 && (tempCol-1)<s && table[tempRow+1][tempCol-1]==' '){q.push(tempRow+1);q.push(tempCol-1);}
    if((tempRow+1)>=0 && (tempRow+1)<s && (tempCol)>=0 && (tempCol)<s && table[tempRow+1][tempCol]==' '){q.push(tempRow+1);q.push(tempCol);}
    if((tempRow+1)>=0 && (tempRow+1)<s && (tempCol+1)>=0 && (tempCol+1)<s && table[tempRow+1][tempCol+1]==' '){q.push(tempRow+1);q.push(tempCol+1);}

    view[tempRow][tempCol]=' ';

    q.pop();
    q.pop();
}
```

Why do I get an infinite loop?

Comment: And what is the problem? Please elaborate further

Comment: PS: row and col are the indexes of the clicked cell

Comment: @whoan Thanks for ur response .. the problem is that this loop is an infinite loop

Comment: Are `table` and `view` somehow related? Does changing `view` affects your conditions upon `table`? I don't think so.

Comment: table is preset with the actual values of cells (mines, spaces, numbers)

Comment: view is preset with all closed value, when one is opened .. the table value of the same cell is copied to it at the same place

Comment: try printing the length of the queue each time through the loop, for debugging purposes; that'll give you your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of problem appears in multiple situations.  It's actually calculating the 'closure' of a set of instances.  Often also found when handling graphs, ...

It's typically solved in the following way:

- Define a `queue` that will store all the elements that need to be processed.
- Define an associative container (`set`) with a key that identifies the items to process and make sure look up is fast (in your case, the key could be the coordinates of the cell)
- Add the first element to the `queue` and `set`
- In a loop, do the following

  - Pop the first element from the `queue`
  - Do whatever you need to do with this element (e.g. `element.process()`)
  - Take all the connected elements (in your case the neighbors) and do the following:

    - if the element is already in the `set`, ignore it
    - if it is not in the `set`, add it to the `set` and push it on the `queue`

The principle is that you push neighbors on the `queue` if they are not yet in the `queue` or have not yet been processed (that's why we need the `set`, to do the efficient look up).

Depending on your exact problem, you could optimize some things, e.g. instead of using a `set`, use a 2-dimensional matrix, or `bitset`.  This will probably take more memory (depending on your grid size), and might give performance problems if you need to reset the matrix often, but will give an `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(log N)` look up for the `set` (even an `std::unordered_set` is slower than a simple indexing lookup in a matrix).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your loop reprocesses cells it's already processed, never stopping.

I would normally go into detail, but frankly your code is difficult to follow, so I've rewritten it for clarity and future readers.

Note that this should be correct but I haven't tested to confirm.

```
const char empty_cell = ' ';
const char open_cell = 'O'; // This should be something different from empty_cell to help you debug.

const int max_rows = 100; // Replace with your max rows.
const int max_cols = 100; // Replace with your max cols.

// For clarity; means "cell position".
typedef std::pair<int, int> cell_pos;

std::queue<cell_pos> pending;
std::vector<cell_pos> skip; 
// skip should really be an std::unordered_set,
// but I leave it as an exercise for the reader.

// Renamed "row" to "start_row"
// Renamed "col" to "start_col"
pending.push(cell_pos(start_row, start_col));

while (!pending.empty()) {
    auto current = pending.front();
    auto row = current.first;
    auto col = current.second;

    // Requires <algorithm>. This skips the current cell if it's already been processed.
    if (std::find(skip.begin(), skip.end(), current) != skip.end()) {
        continue;
    }

    auto left_row = row - 1;
    auto right_row = row + 1;
    auto top_col = col - 1;
    auto bottom_col = col + 1;

    // Is the left cell empty?
    if (left_row >= 0 && table[left_row][col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(left_row, col));
    }
    // Is the right cell empty?
    if (right_row < max_rows && table[right_row][col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(right_row, col));
    }
    // Is the top cell empty?
    if (top_col >= 0 && table[row][top_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(row, top_col));
    }
    // is the bottom cell empty?
    if (bottom_col < max_cols && table[row][bottom_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(row, bottom_col));
    }
    // Is the top-left cell empty?
    if (left_row >= 0 && top_col >= 0 && table[left_row][top_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(left_row, top_col));
    }
    // Is the top-right cell empty?
    if (right_row < max_rows && top_col >= 0 && table[right_row][top_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(right_row, top_col));
    }
    // Is the bottom-left cell empty?
    if (left_row >= 0 && bottom_col < max_cols && table[left_row][bottom_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(left_row, bottom_col));
    }
    // Is the bottom-right cell empty?
    if (right_row < max_rows && bottom_col < max_cols && table[right_row][bottom_col] == empty_cell) {
        pending.push(cell_pos(right_row, bottom_col));
    }

    view[row][col] = open_cell;
    pending.pop();
    skip.push_back(current);
}
```